# Getting a GIT change summary like GitHub

Tags: git, github

I've got a group of developers which make GIT commit and merge mistakes (once in a while).

I would like to monitor for 'large changes' somehow.  I see in GitHub that they have the following line when looking at the details of a specific commit:

> Showing 759 changed files with 21,736 additions and 3,237 deletions.

That is an example of a real merge that should have only had 1 file changed and several additions/deletions.

Is there some way or some tool that exists that would send out an alert via email or SMS when a commit breaches a configured threshold?

If not, I was wondering if it was possible to generate that same type of output using the GIT command line.  That way, if no tool exists, I can easily script it and send out an email with my own tools.

---

**Update: 2014-03-20 18:52**

Based on **nulltoken**'s suggestion, I've tried the following command:

> git diff --shortstat $(git rev-parse HEAD HEAD^)

And got exactly what I needed (for the very last commit anyway).  Oddly enough though, what I just observed is that GitHub (1) provides the following numbers, compared to what my GIT  provides (2):

> 1 :  759 changed files with 21,736 additions and 3,237 deletions.
>
> 2 :  759 files changed, 3237 insertions(+), 21736 deletions(-)

So somebody clearly has a bug!  Either GitHub or my GIT (version 1.7.10.4)... funny!

---

**Update: 2014-03-20 19:05**

Correction, I simply inverted my hashes and it fixed it... my mistake!  No bug to report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if it was possible to generate that same type of output using the GIT command line. That way, if no tool exists, I can easily script it and send out an email with my own tools.

You may be after one of the following options of **[git diff](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)**

- `git diff --stat <from_commit> <until_commit>`
- `git diff --shortstat <from_commit> <until_commit>`

---

Those commands, when ran against the **[LibGit2Sharp](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp)** project, output the following

```
$ git diff --stat a4c6c45 14ab41c
 LibGit2Sharp.Tests/StashFixture.cs  |  3 ++-
 LibGit2Sharp/Core/NativeMethods.cs  |  8 +++-----
 LibGit2Sharp/Core/Proxy.cs          | 18 +++++++++---
 LibGit2Sharp/ReferenceCollection.cs |  5 ++++-
 4 files changed, 18 insertions(+), 16 deletions(-)

$ git diff --shortstat a4c6c45 14ab41c
 4 files changed, 18 insertions(+), 16 deletions(-)
```

You'll note that this is pretty much the same content than from the **[GitHub page showcasing](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/compare/14ab41c...a4c6c45)** those changes (*Note:* Clicking on the *"Show Diff Stats"* will show the per file counts).